# how to ignore first two bytes hdfs writeUTF and writeChars?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have written some data in hdfs, but i want that to be without the first two bytes that the writeUTF() method writes. I want to copy this first two byte free hdfs file to local file and do some analysis on it.

```
if (fs.exists(filenamePath)) {
        // remove the file first
        //fs.delete(filenamePath);
         out = fs.append(filenamePath);
    }
    // create if file doesnt exists
    else{
        out = fs.create(filenamePath);
    }

    out.writeUTF(getFeaturesString(searchCriteriaList,fileNameData));
    out.close();
```

The data written is as follows

```
0aEX Series ex4200-24f....
```

I want only

```
EX Series   ex4200-24f
```

I write all the data to hdfs file and then I am copying the file into local to do some analysis. Is there an alternative method to accomplish this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to ignore first two bytes hdfs `writeUTF()` and `writeChars()`?

You've just answered your own question. Use `writeChars()`.

`writeUTF()` is only useful when somebody is going to be calling `readUTF()` to read it. It uses a modified character set and a length-word that is only understood by `readUTF()`.

There's no particular reason to use `DataOutputStream` here either. If the data is all text, use a `BufferedWriter.`

Comment: I am not getting special chars in beginning of file when i use writeChars() method, but I am getting unwanted spaces after each letter. eg :'E X  S e r i e s' . I am able to do my work but i just wanted to know about this behavior